# Why is my WiX generated msi installing to the wrong directory

Tags: cmd, wix

I'm trying to write a batch script using the Wix command line toolset to build an .msi file from both a Heat generated and a custom .wxs file.

The batch script below is currently building the .msi file correctly for the most part. However, when ran it's installing the binaries straight to the C: drive, instead of installing them to the installation folder specified in the custom wxs file.

Can someone point out what I'm missing because I'm at a loss.

Batch script:

```
"%WIX%bin\heat" dir .\bin\ -srd -gg -pog:Binaries -cg AppBinComponentGroup -out .\AppHeatGen.wxs
"%WIX%bin\candle" .\*.wxs -o .\wixbuild\wixobj\
"%WIX%bin\light" -b .\bin\ .\wixbuild\wixobj\*.wixobj -o .\wixbuild\wixbin\AppInstaller.msi
```

Custom wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="App" Language="1033" Version="1.0.1.0">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="App" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="AppBinComponentGroup" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
    <SetDirectory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="C:\InstallDir" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="App" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: I am not seeing where you defined `APPLICATIONFOLDER`. If wix can't tell which folder that is, the nested folders won't matter. TARGETDIR represents the root of the drive with the most free space available (if multiple drives are available) so that appear to be the drive C: in your case

Comment: @peterpie I thought the SetDirectory tag was defining the APPLICATIONFOLDER value. At least, I thought that's how it worked when I was building the wixproj through MSBuild. How do I need to define that variable then?

Comment: My apologies. I usually never use SetDirectory. If it works the way I think, then it is duplicating the root path ending up like 'C:\C:\InstallDir\App'. I would suggest you update your set directory line to 
`<SetDirectory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="InstallDir" />`. 

The way I usually do it as follows, 

`<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="InstallDir">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="App" />
       </Directory>
  </Directory>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different things with the wix scripts, I found that the heat command was setting all of the Component Directory values to TARGETDIR.

The fix was to update the heat command to include a -dr tag w/ the the desired installation folder id as the value.

```
"%WIX%bin\heat" dir .\bin\ -dr INSTALLFOLDER -srd -gg -pog:Binaries -cg AppBinComponentGroup -out .\AppHeatGen.wxs
```